# Where are multiple stacks and heaps put in virtual memory?

Tags: operating-system, heap-memory, virtual-memory, stack-memory

I'm writing a kernel and need (and want) to put multiple stacks and heaps into virtual memory, but I can't figure out how to place them efficiently. How do normal programs do it?

How (or where) are stacks and heaps placed into the limited virtual memory provided by a 32-bit system, such that they have as much growing space as possible?

For example, when a trivial program is loaded into memory, the layout of its address space might look like this:

```
[  Code  Data  BSS  Heap->  ...  <-Stack  ]
```

In this case the heap can grow as big as virtual memory allows (e.g. up to the stack), and I believe this is how the heap works for most programs. There is no predefined upper bound.

Many programs have shared libraries that are put somewhere in the virtual address space. 
Then there are multi-threaded programs that have multiple stacks, one for each thread. And .NET programs have [multiple heaps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163791.aspx#S1), all of which have to be able to grow one way or another.

I just don't see how this is done reasonably efficient without putting a predefined limit on the size of all heaps and stacks.

Answer (score 3):

I'll assume you have the basics in your kernel done, a trap handler for page faults that can map a virtual memory page to RAM.  Next level up, you need a virtual memory address space manager from which usermode code can request address space.  Pick a segment granularity that prevents excessive fragmentation, 64KB (16 pages) is a good number.  Allow usermode code to both reserve space and commit space.  A simple bitmap of 4GB/64KB = 64K x 2 bits to keep track of segment state gets the job done.  The page fault trap handler also needs to consult this bitmap to know whether the page request is valid or not.

A stack is a fixed size VM allocation, typically 1 megabyte.  A thread usually only needs a handful of pages of it, depending on function nesting level, so reserve the 1MB and commit only the top few pages.  When the thread nests deeper, it will trip a page fault and the kernel can simply map the extra page to RAM to allow the thread to continue.  You'll want to mark the bottom few pages as special, when the thread page faults on those, you declare this website's name.

The most important job of the heap manager is to prevent fragmentation.  The best way to do that is to create a lookaside list that partitions heap requests by size.  Everything less than 8 bytes comes from the first list of segments.  8 to 16 from the second, 16 to 32 from the third, etcetera.  Increasing the size bucket as you go up.  You'll have to play with the bucket sizes to get the best balance.  Very large allocations come directly from the VM address manager.

The first time an entry in the lookaside list is hit, you allocate a new VM segment.  You subdivide the segment into smaller blocks with a linked list.  When such an allocation is released, you add the block to the list of free blocks.  All blocks have the same size regardless of the program request so there won't be any fragmentation.  When the segment is fully used and no free blocks are available you allocate a new segment.  When a segment contains nothing but free blocks you can return it to the VM manager.

This scheme allows you to create any number of stacks and heaps.

Comment: You nicely describe how a heap works, but I don't see how this 'scheme' allows me to create any number of heaps. If I reserve 16 MB for the first heap right after the user's code and data, then where do I put a second heap? Right after the first? Then the first heap can't grow beyond its initial 16 MB. Or fragment that heap on expansion (split the heap), but that's bad for cache locality (e.g. high frequency heap), max object size (e.g. large object heap), garbage collection, or for whatever reason multiple heaps are used. E.g. .NET has many heaps, how do they do it?

Comment: You are missing the part where the heap allocations are segments, not a fixed size.  A heap will have many segments when it grows, they can be scattered throughout the address space.  Cache locality is generally very good because arrays have fixed size elements that come from the same lookaside list chain.

Answer (score 0):

Simply put, as your system resources are always finite, you can't go limitless.

Memory management always consists of several layers each having its well defined responsibility. From the perspective of the program, the application-level manager is visible that is usually concerned only with its own single allocated heap. A level above could deal with creating the multiple heaps if needed out of (its) one global heap and assigning them to subprograms (each with its own memory manager). Above that could be the standard `malloc()`/`free()` that it uses and above those the operating system dealing with pages and actual memory allocation per process (it is basically not concerned not only about multiple heaps, but even user-level heaps in general).

Memory management is costly and so is trapping into the kernel. Combining the two could impose severe performance hit, so what seems to be the actual heap management from the application's point of view is actually implemented in user space (the C runtime library) for the sake of performance (and other reason out of scope for now).

When loading a shared (DLL) library, if it is loaded at program startup, it will of course be most probably loaded to CODE/DATA/etc so no heap fragmentation occurs. On the other hand, if it is loaded at runtime, there's pretty much no other chance than using up heap space.
Static libraries are, of course, simply linked into the CODE/DATA/BSS/etc sections.

At the end of the day, you'll need to impose limits to heaps and stacks so that they're not likely to overflow, but you can allocate others.
If one needs to grow beyond that limit, you can either

- Terminate the application with error
- Have the memory manager allocate/resize/move the memory block for that stack/heap and most probably defragment the heap (its own level) afterwards; that's why `free()` usually performs poorly.

Considering a pretty large, 1KB stack frame on every `call` as an average (might happen if the application developer is unexperienced) a 10MB stack would be sufficient for 10240 nested `call` -s. BTW, besides that, there's pretty much no need for more than one stack and heap per thread.

Comment: But switching between threads should not switch the entire address space (and cause the TLB to be flushed), so for each of every thread used by a process, its stack _must_ be present in the process' address space. And the link in my post shows an image of how a CLR process has very many heaps. So there _is_ a need for more than one stack and heap in one address space.

Comment: The address space is a very different level of abstraction. Actually, in this case you have those multiple stacks and heaps in the very same address space. The address space itself is managed by the OS whereas the heap is not; it is managed by user-level library code.